# Js not working in separate js file when i use multiple functions from different libraries

Tags: jquery, function, file

I am using multiple other libraries in my template to achieve the desired results. It's a web template.

- Magnific popup ([Link](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)) For Popups
- owl carousel ([Link](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)) For Sliders
- Isotope ([Link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)) For Filtrables
- FileStyule ([Link](http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/)) For Styling File select field

Now, i want to manage all these libraries functions in one single file, to do this i have created a file called `"app.js"` and i have included this file in all of my template files `".html files"`.

Now, when i run them in browser, it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function(…)` for those functions that i am not using on that specific page which is currently running in the browser.

**Question:**
What should i do to manage all the these functions in single and file and make the run for all the pages.

**EDIT**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/bootstrap-filestyle-1.2.1/src/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/Magnific-Popup-master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show us how you are loading these files.  Typically, you need to load jQuery first, then all the additional libraries.  We can't tell if this is what you are doing or not.

Comment: you might be using a jquery version too old for the plugins.  Can you use a more recent version? (latest perhaps?) - any other errors show up in console?

Comment: I guess, it's because i am using the function file on a page where there is no id is specified for it. That's why it is giving error `owlCarousel  is not a function`.

I am getting this error where i am NOT using owl slider.